# How a class is loaded by two class loader(assume both are URLClassLoader) at the same level in the java Class-loader loader Hierarchy

Tags: java, classloader

Recently i have started learning How exactly classloader works in Java. Below are three points which i have oberserved:

**Point-1:** Each class loader has a parent class loader. When a class loader is asked to load a class or resource, it consults its parent class loader before attempting to load the item itself. The parent in turn consults its parent, and so on. So it is only after all of the ancestor class loaders cannot find the item that the current class loader gets involved.

**Point-2:** same class loaded by two loader treated as two different class entity. we can't even cast one class(loader 1) object to another class(loaded by loader2). it will throw ClassCastException.

**Point-3:** A child class loader can check the cache of the parent class loader, but the parent cannot see classes loaded 
   by the child.

Based on the above points i have two questions:

**Situation:** I have created a URLClassloader object url1 and another URLClassloader object url2 in the same application. as we know by default both classloader will have the same parent classloader. just assume here parent class loader is SystemClassLoader.

**Question 1:** url1 classloader has loaded a class A.class from location x/abc.jar. again url2 wants to load same class from the same 
   location. will url2 load the freshly or will use the same one loaded by url1? I tried to check, only once static block was getting executed so beleived class is getting loadded only once. which as per my understanding not satisfying Point-1 and Point-3.

**Question 2:** does url2 class loader can check the cache of url1 class loader. related to Point-3.

Answer (score 0):

The classloaders are entirely independent, so you get two different classes.

Since you didn't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example), here is one using an arbitrarily selected .jar file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jarFile = "/path/to/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar";

    URLClassLoader url1 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File(jarFile).toURI().toURL() });
    URLClassLoader url2 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File(jarFile).toURI().toURL() });

    Class<?> fractionClass1 = url1.loadClass("org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction");
    Class<?> fractionClass2 = url2.loadClass("org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction");

    Object oneHalf1 = fractionClass1.getField("ONE_HALF").get(null);
    Object oneHalf2 = fractionClass2.getField("ONE_HALF").get(null);

    System.out.println("url1 = " + url1);
    System.out.println("url2 = " + url2);
    System.out.println(" Same? " + (url1 == url2));
    System.out.println("fractionClass1 = " + fractionClass1);
    System.out.println("fractionClass2 = " + fractionClass2);
    System.out.println(" Same? " + (fractionClass1 == fractionClass2));
    System.out.println("oneHalf1 = " + oneHalf1);
    System.out.println("oneHalf2 = " + oneHalf2);
    System.out.println(" Same? " + (oneHalf1 == oneHalf2));
}
```

*Output*

```
url1 = java.net.URLClassLoader@1e81f4dc
url2 = java.net.URLClassLoader@4d591d15
 Same? false
fractionClass1 = class org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction
fractionClass2 = class org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction
 Same? false
oneHalf1 = 1/2
oneHalf2 = 1/2
 Same? false
```